# distribution of $\sup\limits_{0\le t \le 1}|W(t)|$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

My prof on class told us that distribution of  $S=\sup\limits_{0\le t \le 1}|W(t)|$ has been well studied, where $W$ is a Wiener process, but I need a table to find $c$ such that $P(S < c) = 0.95$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in Feller volume 2, and on page 2 of [this paper](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/784874/filename/Estimation_max_process_121023.pdf).

[image]